# How to configure the working directory for monaco editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, monaco-editor

I use `monaco-editor@0.10.0` in `electron`, I extended the following example for my case
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/sample-electron/index.html

I wonder if is there any way to set working directory for `require` and `import` statements.
E.g. I have file `dependency.js` and I want to have auto complete in editor for the following statement:

```
import dep from './dependency.js'
```

I've tried to setup typescript/javascript compiler with options `baseUrl`, `rootDirs`, but unsuccessfully.

```
baseUrl: 'file://pathToDir/'
//or
rootDirs: ['file://pathToDir/']
```